# ListPreference causing inflate error on PreferenceActivity

Tags: android, android-preferences, listpreference

I'm trying a really simple PreferenceActivity and it's working fine with EditTextPreference but it always throws this error when I add a ListPreference (line 16 is the ListPreference line):

> 11-06 15:15:02.746: E/AndroidRuntime(11607): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>   11-06 15:15:02.746: E/AndroidRuntime(11607): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{br.com.mtcbrasilia.aa/br.com.mtcbrasilia.aa.PreferencesActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #16: Error inflating class java.lang.reflect.Constructor
>   11-06 15:15:02.746: E/AndroidRuntime(11607):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2247)
>   11-06 15:15:02.746: E/AndroidRuntime(11607):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2297)
>   11-06 15:15:02.746: E/AndroidRuntime(11607):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:152)
>   11-06 15:15:02.746: E/AndroidRuntime(11607):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1282)
>   11-06 15:15:02.746: E/AndroidRuntime(11607):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
>   11-06 15:15:02.746: E/AndroidRuntime(11607):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
>   11-06 15:15:02.746: E/AndroidRuntime(11607):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5328)
>   11-06 15:15:02.746: E/AndroidRuntime(11607):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>   11-06 15:15:02.746: E/AndroidRuntime(11607):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
>   11-06 15:15:02.746: E/AndroidRuntime(11607):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1102)
>   11-06 15:15:02.746: E/AndroidRuntime(11607):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:869)
>   11-06 15:15:02.746: E/AndroidRuntime(11607):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
>   11-06 15:15:02.746: E/AndroidRuntime(11607): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #16: Error inflating class java.lang.reflect.Constructor
>   11-06 15:15:02.746: E/AndroidRuntime(11607):    at android.preference.GenericInflater.createItem(GenericInflater.java:397)
>   11-06 15:15:02.746: E/AndroidRuntime(11607):    at android.preference.GenericInflater.onCreateItem(GenericInflater.java:417)
>   11-06 15:15:02.746: E/AndroidRuntime(11607):    at android.preference.GenericInflater.createItemFromTag(GenericInflater.java:428)
>   11-06 15:15:02.746: E/AndroidRuntime(11607):    at android.preference.GenericInflater.rInflate(GenericInflater.java:481)
>   11-06 15:15:02.746: E/AndroidRuntime(11607):    at android.preference.GenericInflater.inflate(GenericInflater.java:326)
>   11-06 15:15:02.746: E/AndroidRuntime(11607):    at android.preference.GenericInflater.inflate(GenericInflater.java:263)
>   11-06 15:15:02.746: E/AndroidRuntime(11607):    at android.preference.PreferenceManager.inflateFromResource(PreferenceManager.java:269)
>   11-06 15:15:02.746: E/AndroidRuntime(11607):    at android.preference.PreferenceActivity.addPreferencesFromResource(PreferenceActivity.java:1531)
>   11-06 15:15:02.746: E/AndroidRuntime(11607):    at br.com.mtcbrasilia.aa.PreferencesActivity.onCreate(PreferencesActivity.java:12)
>   11-06 15:15:02.746: E/AndroidRuntime(11607):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5250)
>   11-06 15:15:02.746: E/AndroidRuntime(11607):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1097)
>   11-06 15:15:02.746: E/AndroidRuntime(11607):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2211)
>   11-06 15:15:02.746: E/AndroidRuntime(11607):    ... 11 more
>   11-06 15:15:02.746: E/AndroidRuntime(11607): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
>   11-06 15:15:02.746: E/AndroidRuntime(11607):    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
>   11-06 15:15:02.746: E/AndroidRuntime(11607):    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:417)
>   11-06 15:15:02.746: E/AndroidRuntime(11607):    at android.preference.GenericInflater.createItem(GenericInflater.java:383)
>   11-06 15:15:02.746: E/AndroidRuntime(11607):    ... 22 more
>   11-06 15:15:02.746: E/AndroidRuntime(11607): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
>   11-06 15:15:02.746: E/AndroidRuntime(11607):    at android.content.res.AssetManager.getResourceTextArray(AssetManager.java:214)
>   11-06 15:15:02.746: E/AndroidRuntime(11607):    at android.content.res.Resources.getTextArray(Resources.java:1273)
>   11-06 15:15:02.746: E/AndroidRuntime(11607):    at android.content.res.TypedArray.getTextArray(TypedArray.java:629)
>   11-06 15:15:02.746: E/AndroidRuntime(11607):    at android.preference.ListPreference.(ListPreference.java:50)
>   11-06 15:15:02.746: E/AndroidRuntime(11607):    ... 25 more

Here's my res/xml/preferences.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<EditTextPreference
    android:title="test"
    android:summary="summary test"
    android:key="testKey"/>

<ListPreference android:key="languagePref"
                android:entries="@array/menu_pref_language_titles"
                android:summary="bla bla"
                android:entryValues="@array/menu_pref_language_codes"
                android:title="@string/pref_language" />
```

My PreferencesActivity:

```
public class PreferencesActivity extends PreferenceActivity {

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences);
    }

}
```

My strings.xml:

```
<string name="pref_language">Language:</string>

<string name="pref_language_default">default</string>

<string-array name="menu_pref_language">
    <item>Device default</item>
    <item>English</item>
    <item>Portuguese</item>
</string-array>

<string-array name="menu_pref_language_codes">
    <item>default</item>
    <item>en</item>
    <item>pt</item>
</string-array>
```

And my Manifest:

```
<activity
        android:name=".PreferencesActivity"
        android:label="@string/action_settings"
        android:launchMode="standard"
        >
    </activity>
```

My target sdks are 11 to 18 (for now) and it's not working on 18 (I'm having problems with my emulators). I know I could use PreferenceFragment but I intend to target older sdks later.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the preference file you have:

```
android:entries="@array/menu_pref_language_titles"
```

in the strings file you have

```
name="menu_pref_language"
```

Comment: Oh boy... stupid error was making me crazy for an hour! Localization mistakes... Thank you for the keen eye!

Comment: You're welcome. It's amazing how often a fresh set of eyes sees the problem.